# Replace a switch statement with multiple assignments to object literal

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a switch statement that I'd like to replace with an object literal but because multiple assignments are made for each case, I don't know how to do it.

```
switch (roll1) {
    case 21:
        rain = 1.25;
        break;
    case 22:
        rain = 1.5;
        solid = "light";
        break;
    case 23:
        rain = 1.75;
        solid = "light";
        break;
    case 24:
        rain = 2;
        solid = "light";
        break;
    case 25:
        rain = 2.25;
        solid = "medium";
        break;
    case 26:
        rain = 2.5;
        solid = "medium";
        hook = 1;
        break;
    case 27:
        rain = 2.75;
        solid = "medium";
        hook = 5;
        break;
    case 28:
        rain = 3;
        solid = "heavy";
        hook = 10;
        break;
    case 29:
        rain = 3.25;
        solid = "heavy";
        hook = 15;
        break;
    case 30:
        rain = 3.5;
        solid = "heavy";
        hook = 20;
}
return [rain,solid,hook];
```

Note: solid & hook are given default values before the switch statement.  I was looking at this example:

```
const dogSwitch = (breed) => ({
  "border": "Border Collies are good boys and girls.",
  "border2": "Border Collies are good boys and girls.",
  "pitbull": "Pit Bulls are good boys and girls.",
  "german": "German Shepherds are good boys and girls."
})[breed]
console.log(dogSwitch("border2"))
```

But each line of the object literal only assigns one value, not multiple. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define object like below and then use Object destructuring to retrieve values for specified variables:

```js
let doc = { 23: { rain: 1.25 }, 22: { rain: 1.5, solid: "light" }, 29: { rain: 3.25, solid: "heavy", hook: 20 } };

let {rain, solid, hook} = doc[29];

console.log(solid);
console.log(rain);
console.log(hook);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move it to Objects to handle it.

```
const getRollProps = (roll1) => {
  const caseList = {
    "21": {
      "rain": 1.25
    },
    "22": {
      "rain": 1.5,
      "solid": "light"
    },
    "23": {
      "rain": 1.75,
      "solid": "light"
    },
    "24": {
      "rain": 2,
      "solid": "light"
    },
    "25": {
      "rain": 2.25,
      "solid": "medium"
    },
    "26": {
      "rain": 2.5,
      "solid": "medium",
      "hook": 1
    },
    "27": {
      "rain": 2.75,
      "solid": "medium",
      "hook": 5
    },
    "28": {
      "rain": 3,
      "solid": "heavy",
      "hook": 10
    },
    "29": {
      "rain": 3.25,
      "solid": "heavy",
      "hook": 15
    },
    "30": {
      "rain": 3.5,
      "solid": "heavy",
      "hook": 20
    }
  };

  const {rain, solid, hook} = (caseList[roll1] || {});
  return [rain, solid, hook];
}

getRollProps(22);
```